# Excel VBA: Find string within string with wildcard

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to find a string within another where I do not know the exact form and to use wildcards.

In this case I have a JSON object of the form:

```
json_object = "{'id':'id1', 'name':'name1', 'location':'location1'},
               {'id':'id2', 'name':'name2', 'location':'location2'},
               {'id':'id3', 'name':'name3', 'location':'location3'}"
```

I want to find the position of the string `"{'id':'id2', 'name':'name2', 'location':'location2'}"`, where I do not know the id or location (which can be of variable length) but only the name.

So, something like an InStr function if you could use wildcards:

```
string_start = InStr(json_object, "{'id':'*', 'name':'name2', 'location':'*'}")
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a different approach:

```
string_start = StrRev(json_object, "{'id':", InStr(json_object, "'name2'"))
```

Might need a minor tweak with a +1 or -1 to ensure you're getting the first character.